# is there a term for doing this: func1(func2(), func3());

Tags: terminology

I know that `obj.func1().func2()` is called method chaining, but what is the technical term for:

```
func1(func2(), func3());
```

Where return of a function is used as an argument to another.

Comment: `obj.func1().func2() is called method chaining` - Correction: It's called a train wreck.

Comment: That sounds very, very, very tricky unless you're absolutely sure that `obj.func1()` always returns an object that has `func2()` as a member function.

Comment: @Yam Care to explain? It’s employed for great profit in fluent interfaces, amongst others. Are you referring to the Law of Demeter? If so, this doesn’t forbid the above pattern, and even in cases where it does there is a good case against the LoD.

Comment: method chaining lies on one shelf with syntactic sugar, no need to make a fuss over it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph train wreck reefers  to the debug-mess you'll fine yourself in when one of the methods in the chain fails. Ie. a Null Reference Exception on line 345 - great, which one of the 13 methods where you saying it was? oh, you didn't, right.

Comment: @PauliØsterø I thought that's what stack tracing is meant for.

Comment: @CCRicers your stacktrace cant tell you which one of the 13 methods thas is trying to call something on a null - it only shows you a trace to the method actually having the train wreck inside it, no?

Comment: @Pauli Well that then depends on the language / API you’re using. For instance, a null-reference-free style of programming makes this much easier. Also, the same applies to *any* complex expression in code. Do you suggest refactoring them all into an equivalent of three-address codes (i.e. using two operands and one operator)?

Comment: `parser
  .setOption1(111)
  .setOption2("aaa").parse()` Properly indented.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't think it's function composition. Function composition means taking two or more functions and turning them into a new function, like `f . g . h` in Haskell. Note that no function is called at this point.

Personally, I would refer to constructs like `func1(func2(), func3())` as "nested function calls".

Comment: +1, it's referred to as "nested function calls" in all programming contexts I've seen.

Comment: +1, calling this "function composition" is deceptively wrong.

Comment: +1.  All `f(g())` is doing is calling `f()` with an expression for the first argument, and it so happens the function call `g()` qualifies as an expression.  But if there has to be a name for it, this is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 16):

In mathematics, it's called [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).  I don't think I've heard the term applied to programming, though.  That may be because the usage is largely avoided for a few reasons.  It can introduce strange bugs when the functions have side effects, due to compilers being free to evaluate func3 before func2.  It's more difficult to debug because you can't set breakpoints on or print out intermediate results, and most people just plain find it harder to read.

Comment: It's called composition in functional programming as well.

Comment: I often see/hear it called 'nested function call' as well, although this term may be somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: I don't think it's "largely avoided". IMO it's not uncommon to write code like `printf("%d %d\n", strlen(a), strlen(b));` instead of using intermediary variables.

Comment: I think the solution to the strange bugs when the functions have side-effects is not to avoid this, but instead to avoid writing functions that produce values and have side-effects. Similarly, regarding the debuggers, the solution should be to ask for a better debugger, one that doesn't force you to change your code to make the debugger work.

Comment: Whether the compiler free to evaluate func3 before func2 depends entirely on the language being used. In Java, for example, the evaluation order is strictly specified. I'd actually suspect that this is the case for most languages.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt:  In C++ and (I think) C, the order is unspecified, which means the compiler is free to evaluate as it likes without documentation.  It can't interleave execution, so either `func2` or `func3` will run all the way to completion and then the other will run.  The solution is to write programs that don't depend on unspecified behavior.

Comment: The term "function composition" in mathematics actually only applies to single-argument functions, where it refers to a structure of the form `func1(func2(func3(x)))`. Or technically, it refers to the _functions_ themselves: if `g(x) = f1(f2(f3(x)))`, then `g` (_not_ `g(x)`) is the composition of `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`. While I could see a way in which you could call the structure in the question "function composition," it strikes me as a very unusual use of the term, in a mathematical sense.

Comment: -1, function composition in programming is more like (to borrow Python's syntax): `newfunc = lambda x, y : func1(func2(x), func3(y))`.  Then you've "composed" a new function that can be called later: `newfunc(x, y)`

Answer (score 2):

As @Karl Bielefeldt points, it's called function composition in Math.

There is NO technical term for this thing in programming. And I think this is a Good thing, because it indicates that the operation is normal and **Orthogonal**.

Orthogonality in programming languages means that you can use an instruction/operation **independent of it's context**. For example, you can call a function/method in all of the following ways, and it would behave the same...

```
f1()(f2(), f3());

x = y + f4();

if ( f5() && !f6() ) doSomething();

f7() = f8() + f9(); // in C++ when a function returns a reference

x = f10() ? f11(f12(f13(x))) : f14();
```

You can read more on Orthogonality in Programming on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_(programming)), and there's a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527393/what-is-orthogonality) on this.

Comment: It's not indicating orthogonality but depending on that.

Comment: +1 you're just passing values, there's no magic in the OP's call

Answer (score 1):

I really am not that good with terms, but I just read an article a few days ago that referred to the term [Higher order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), and here's an abstract of the definition per Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

> In mathematics and computer science, higher-order functions,
> functional forms, or functionals are functions which do at least one
> of the following:
>
> - take one or more functions as an input
> - output a function
>
> All other functions are first-order functions. In mathematics
> higher-order functions are also known as operators or functionals. The
> derivative in calculus is a common example, since it maps a function
> to another function.

so in this case, since that scenario does take at least one function as an input/param, it'd be considered a higher order function, i believe.

Comment: No, calling a higher order function would look like `func1(func2, func3)`. Note the absent parenthesis.

Comment: that makes sense Fred. one's the address of a function, and the other the result of executing that function. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @fredoverflow `func2` and `func3` could be higher-order functions themselves and *return* a new function when called.